# Instrument linux kernel local interrupt handling on x86-64

Tags: c, linux-kernel, x86-64, interrupt-handling

I would like to write some code (for example as a small kernel module) to instrument local interrupts on Linux running on the x86-64 architecture, i.e. I would like to write some kind of handler that is called by the kernel every time a local interrupt is triggered by the APIC.

The handler would then check whether a certain process is currently running and inspect said process' memory.

I realize that what I am trying to do may not be good engineering practice, but my aim is to create a hacky one-off solution for exploration/research purposes.

In the ideal case, there would be some kind of function similar to  `request_irq` [1] (which as far as I can tell is used for handling interrupts from devices like keyboards, network cards, ...) allowing me to tell the kernel to run my code every time a local timer interrupt occurs.

Does anybody have any pointers on how to accomplish this?

Does the kernel provide an API for registering a handler for local interrupts?

If not, I could directly modify the kernel's source code for handling interrupts. Where in the kernel would I find this code?

**Edit**: Here is what my research so far has found.
TLDR:`request_irq` is **not** the way to hook local timer interrupts.

According to Understanding the Linux Kernel, Table 4.2 [2], the interrupt vector `0xef` is allocated to Local APIC timer interrupts. The kernel source confirms this [3].

Since `request_irq` takes an interrupt vector as its first argument, let's try registering a handler for this vector inside a kernel module:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>    // included for KERN_INFO
#include <linux/init.h>      // included for __init and __exit macros

#include <linux/interrupt.h> // included for IRQF_ and request_irq
#include <linux/irqreturn.h> // included for IRQ_NONE
#include <asm/irq_vectors.h> // included for LOCAL_TIMER_VECTOR

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Instrument local timer interrupts");

static int DEVICE_COOKIE = 1;

static int count = 0;

static irqreturn_t handler(int irq, void *dev) {
    count++;
    return IRQ_NONE;
}

static int __init test_init(void) {
    int status;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Running request_irq\n");
    status = request_irq(
        LOCAL_TIMER_VECTOR,
        &handler,
        IRQF_TIMER,
        "foobar",
        &DEVICE_COOKIE);
    if (status == 0) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Successfully installed handler\n");
        return 0;
    } else {
        printk(
            KERN_INFO "Failed to install handler. error code: %d\n",
            status);
        return -1;
    }
}

static void __exit test_cleanup(void) {
    free_irq(LOCAL_TIMER_VECTOR, &DEVICE_COOKIE);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye kernel. I saw %d interrupts.\n", count);
}

module_init(test_init);
module_exit(test_cleanup);
```

When we try to insert the module with `insmod`, `request_irq` returns `-EINVAL`:

```
[74890.287173] Running request_irq
[74890.287174] Failed to install handler. error code: -22
```

So where does the `-EINVAL` come from?
Reading through the kernel source, we find that `request_irq` is just a wrapper around `request_threaded_irq` [4]. `request_threaded_irq` calls `irq_to_desc` and returns `-EINVAL` if the call fails. We can easily check whether this is the case with another small kernel module:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>    // included for KERN_INFO
#include <linux/init.h>      // included for __init and __exit macros

#include <linux/interrupt.h> // included for IRQF_ and request_irq
#include <linux/irqreturn.h> // included for IRQ_NONE
#include <asm/irq_vectors.h> // included for LOCAL_TIMER_VECTOR
#include <linux/irqnr.h>     // included for irq_to-desc
#include <linux/irqdesc.h>   // included for irq_desc

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Call irq_to_desc(LOCAL_TIMER_VECTOR)");

static int __init test_init(void) {
    struct irq_desc *desc;
    desc = irq_to_desc(LOCAL_TIMER_VECTOR);
    if (!desc) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "irq_to_desc(LOCAL_TIMER_VECTOR) failed");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

static void __exit test_cleanup(void) {
}

module_init(test_init);
module_exit(test_cleanup);
```

And indeed it fails:

```
[75787.142533] irq_to_desc(LOCAL_TIMER_VECTOR) failed
```

[1] www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch06lev1sec3

[2] www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/understanding-the-linux/0596005652/ch04s06.html

[3] lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/irq_vectors.h?v=4.8#L108

[4] lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/irq/manage.c?v=4.8#L1634

Comment: Rather you than me :(

Comment: 'exploration/research purposes' - AKA game hacking..(or worse)

Comment: No, not game hacking. I want to learn more about the behaviour of Intel TSX abort handlers. I don't understand what you meant by "Rather you than me :("?

Comment: Show your code or progress before asking.

Comment: It's unclear the connection between local interrupts and the TSX abort handlers, but perhaps it's because you are developing something new. However, it's still unclear, to me, what are you exactly asking. Do you want to hook every interrupt? Or do you want to detect the triggering of the LINTx pins?

Comment: I am trying to hook every interrupt. (I don't understand what you mean by "detect the triggering of the LINTx pins".)

Comment: @quadgraph, CPU has usually one or in some cases only two interrupt lines. It doesn't know what devices generated it. That's why APIC and other similar HW exists.